# Prove that the integers modulo 8 is not an internal direct product of two proper subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not an internal direct product of two proper subgroups.

I'm really struggling to get the wheels turning on this one. I know what it means for group to be an internal product of two subgroups, I'm just not sure how to get started in showing that $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orders of the factors would have to be $2$ and $4$. Then the product has no elements of order $>4$, but $\Bbb Z_8$ has.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit rusty with group theory, so there may be another way of doing this, but $\mathbb{Z}_4$ only has so many subgroups, in fact it only has 2 proper subgroups so there are only 4 possibilities for you to check. I dont remember if there is an easy way to find the size of a product, but if there is then try to show that non of those things could have size 8. alternatively you can show none of them will have an element of order 8, without needing to compute the entire group in any of the 4 cases.